# Loading a dll into a game

Tags: c++, dll-injection

The situation here is, I have a x64 bit game which loads xinput1_3.dll. My aim is to load my own code into that game by renaming my dll to xinput1_3.dll. I know about the functions which are getting imported from xinput1_3.dll by the game's executable. The thing which I tried out was exporting those function using XInput.lib and XInput.h header within my dll and doing so gave me errors listed below:

`error C2375: 'XInputGetCapabilities' : redefinition; different linkage`

`see declaration of 'XInputGetCapabilities'`

...and the same errors occur for `XInputGetState/XInputSetState`

redirect.h

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include "Xinput.h"

#define IMPORT  __declspec(dllimport)
#define EXPORT  __declspec(dllexport)


EXTERN_C EXPORT DWORD WINAPI XInputGetCapabilities(DWORD dwUserIndex, DWORD dwFlags, XINPUT_CAPABILITIES *pCapabilities);
EXTERN_C EXPORT DWORD WINAPI XInputGetState(DWORD dwUserIndex, XINPUT_STATE *pState);
EXTERN_C EXPORT DWORD WINAPI XInputSetState(DWORD dwUserIndex, XINPUT_VIBRATION *pVibration);
```

dllmain.cpp

```
BOOL WINAPI DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                   DWORD  dwReason,
                   LPVOID lpReserved
                 )
{
    switch (dwReason)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: What you could do is re-link the original xinput1_3.dll by renaming the global symbols, and then load that modified dll in your code, which can then call the original methods.

Comment: I am quite a newbie at dll injection so could you provide a detailed explanation please?

Comment: The compiler has already parsed a declaration for XInputGetCapabilities(), you *redeclared* it but now with a different attribute that does not match the original declaration.  You need to do this either by not #including Xinput.h or by writing a DEF file that forces your function to be exported anyway.

Comment: I tried with a def file too, it gave me few errors of unresolved external symbol